# how to use shared preferences with radio group

Tags: java, android

I have two buttons in next and previous , question textview and their answers option in Radio button . I have to save the radio buttons values in Shared Preferences on click Next button and when i call previous button it gets the Shared Preferences value from next button and set it into radio button when i call the previous button.But after run the application radio button value saves in shared preferences.But When i call previous button does not get the Shared Preferences value and does not show the Radio button is checked. Can some one help me here.Thanks in Advanced.

Here is my Activity code.

```
 read_Questions_XML_File();

          button_Previouse.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    previousQuestionCalled(v);
                }
            });


            button_Next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    nextQuestionCalled(v);
                }
            });


public void nextQuestionCalled(View view)
    {

        int id = Options_RadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
        System.out.println("id = " + id);
        if (id > 0)
        {   

            Options_RadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup R_Group, int checked_ID) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)R_Group. findViewById(checked_ID);
                    int checkedIndex = R_Group.indexOfChild(radioButton);
                    System.out.println("checkedIndex = " + checkedIndex);

                    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("RGROUP_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    editor.putInt("check", checkedIndex);
                    editor.commit(); 


                }
            });


            //if animationForward == false
            if (animationForward)
            {
                storingResult();
                boolean flag;
                if (animationForward)
                {  flag = false; }

                else 
                { flag = true; }

                animationForward = flag;
            }

        //Return The Number Of Element in this Vector > 0
        //-1 + 1
        if (-1 + Vectore_mquestionDatabaseStructure.size() > StaticClass.QuestionNumber)
        {
            if (StaticClass.isTest) 
            {
                StaticClass.resultOfTest_Out_OF = 1 + StaticClass.resultOfTest_Out_OF;
            }

            StaticClass.QuestionNumber = 1 + StaticClass.QuestionNumber;
            reHitting();
            view.clearAnimation();

            if (!StaticClass.isTest) {
                button_QuestionLimit.clearAnimation();
            }

            if (StaticClass.isTest) {
                button_QuestionLimit.clearAnimation();
            }

            return;
        }

        else
        {
            button_QuestionLimit.startAnimation(mAnimation);
            return;
        }
    }

        else if (id == -1)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please Select Any Option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
        }
    }

 public void previousQuestionCalled(View view)
    {
         System.out.println("_________________in Previous Question____________");
         SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MY_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
         int savedRadioIndex = sharedPreferences.getInt("check", 0);
         System.out.println("savedRadioIndex is "+savedRadioIndex);
         RadioButton savedCheckedRadioButton = (RadioButton)Options_RadioGroup.getChildAt(savedRadioIndex);
         savedCheckedRadioButton.setChecked(true);
         System.out.println("_________________in Previous Question____________");

        if (!animationForward)
        {
            boolean flag;

            if (animationForward) 
            {
                flag = false;
            }
            else
            {
                flag = true;
            }
            animationForward = flag;
        }
        if (StaticClass.QuestionNumber > 0)
        {
            if (!StaticClass.isTest)
            {
                StaticClass.QuestionNumber = -1 + StaticClass.QuestionNumber;
                reHitting();
                button_QuestionLimit.clearAnimation();
            }
            view.clearAnimation();


        } 
        else 
        {
            button_QuestionLimit.startAnimation(mAnimation);
        }

    }
```

When i press Next button saved the Shared Prefs Value in = int checkedIndex = R_Group.indexOfChild(radioButton);

But when i press Previous button here I'm getting Shared Prefs Value is zero or -1 and Radio button is unchecked.

Here is my Logcat info

```
10-08 16:47:54.007: I/System.out(459): id = 2131165205
10-08 16:47:54.007: I/System.out(459): strLimit = 2/12
10-08 16:47:54.007: I/System.out(459): ************************IN Next Button******************
10-08 16:47:54.016: I/System.out(459): checkedIndex = 2
10-08 16:47:54.086: I/System.out(459): ************************IN Next Button******************
10-08 16:47:54.086: I/System.out(459): ************************IN Next Button******************
10-08 16:47:54.086: I/System.out(459): checkedIndex = -1
10-08 16:47:54.096: I/System.out(459): ************************IN Next Button******************
10-08 16:48:06.756: I/System.out(459): _________________in Previous Question____________
10-08 16:48:06.756: I/System.out(459): savedRadioIndex is -1
```

After that i have checked xml file from DDMS its not store the value n that .It also store the -1 value .And here log cat shows the shared prefs value.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<map>
<int name="check" value="-1" />
</map>
```

Answer (score 0):

In RadioGroup, you have to create localInstance while you are trying to save to get the current selected choice in RadioGroup. I have created simplest example and 
You can implement as mentioned below :

```
private void saveRadioChoice(){
SharedPreferences mSharedPref = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF_KEY,MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPref.edit();

// Initialize Radiogroup while saving choices
RadioGroup localRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.choices);
editor.putInt(my_choice_key, localRadioGroup.indexOfChild(findViewById(localRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId())));
editor.apply();
}
```

after saving this value, you can retrieve it as follows

```
private void retrieveChoices(){

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREF_KEY,MODE_PRIVATE);
int i = sharedPref.getInt(my_choice_key,-1);
if( i >= 0){
((RadioButton) ((RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.myChoiceViewRadio)).getChildAt(i)).setChecked(true);
}


}
```